# How to setup vagrant with chef_solo without changing cookbooks

Tags: configuration, apache2, chef-infra, vagrant

I am working with [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) and [chef-solo](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners/chef_solo.html), which works really well so far. I do have a common directory for the chef-solo cookbooks, as I want to be able to simply clone an opscode cookbook from their [git repository](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks) and later being able to pull updates. In order to do that, I would like to keep the cookbooks as intact as possible to fast-forward any updates.

The cookbooks of opscode are easily configurable with the `module.json = {}` option in the `Vagrantfile`. However, some options are not configurable, e.g. the ability to set the `AllowOverride None`-Setting or similar.

Therefore, I would like to be able to overwrite files in subsequent directories, similar to overriding a function in OOP. Example: The cookbooks for apache2 contains the default site template in apache2/templates/default/default-site.erb with the aformentioned `AllowOverride None`-Option set. In ProjectA, I would have a default-site.erb overriding the global template with the project specific settings of ProjectA, while ProjectB has no such file and thus will use the global template.

Does anyone have such a setup running or an idea on how to achieve this or a similar good setup?

Comment: Why don't you want to change cookbooks for your benefit? Anyway you can later `pull rebase` or `merge` from opscode repository.

Comment: I've actually searched for the solution of @Axsuul - much easier to use. ;)

Comment: On the note of `pull rebase` and `merge`, I highly recommend using something like https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian if you aren't already using it to manage your cookbooks!

Comment: yeah, I found the librarian-script on another thread. I'll stick with chef-solo and vagrant for now, before I add another layer of complexibility with possible error sources. But thanks for the tip - highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chef Solo supports `site-cookbooks`. For it to work with vagrant, you will need to set it up manually. This is how I define my cookbooks paths in my `Vagrantfile`

```
chef.cookbooks_path = ["kitchen/cookbooks", "kitchen/site-cookbooks"]
```

So anything in `site-cookbooks` will override those in `cookbooks`. For example, `kitchen/site-cookbooks/apache2/templates/default/default-site.erb` will be used instead of `kitchen/cookbooks/apache2/templates/default/default-site.erb`.